# Custom URL Protocol with arguments is looking for the arguments inside Mozilla's directory

Tags: html, firefox, browser, registry

I have a Custom URL Protocol to open Notepad++. In the browser when I type

```
notepad++:C:\test.txt
```

Notepad++ opens but the file does not open. Instead I get this error

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\notepad++:C:\test.txt cannot be opened"
```

I get a similar error in Google Chrome too.

Here is my registry entry.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom URL protocol, by design, passes in the entire protocol as parameters and the entire string "notepad++:C:\test.txt" gets passed to the application. The errors from Firefox are because the argument is not a fully qualified file path, and it's looking for the file inside the working directory of the browser. The way around this is to parse away the "notepad++:", such as with a script, and then have the script launch notepad++, with the correct parameters.

Comment: Hello, can you give me more information about that please? I need to do the same thing than you but with Adobe App (ID, PS,..).